# Where does the error stem from in the process?

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, fpga

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;


entity reset40 is
Port (  CLOCK : in  STD_LOGIC;  --50MHz
        CIKIS : out STD_LOGIC


        );

end reset40;

architecture Behavioral of reset40 is

    signal A:std_logic;
begin

    process(CLOCK)  --line20

        variable fcounter: unsigned(24 downto 0);
        variable counter_A:integer range 0 to 40:=0;

    begin

        if rising_edge (CLOCK) then   
            fcounter := fcounter+1;         
        end if;

        A<=fcounter(6);           --fa=fclock/2^6

        if ((rising_edge (A)) and (counter_A/=40)) then  
            counter_A:= counter_A+1;              
            CIKIS<=A;
        else
            CIKIS<='0';
        end if;

    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

> ERROR:Xst:827 - "C:/Users/reset40/reset40.vhd" line 20: Signal CIKIS
>   cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description
>   style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register,
>   memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.

What is the error about clock? How come is it a 'bad synchronous description'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic mistake is that all the code that is in the process needs to run only on the rising edge of the clock.  This is because the target chip only has flipflops which can respond on one edge.

The process you have written is sensitive to changes in `clock` due to this line:

```
process(clock)
```

so it is sensitive to *both* clock edges.

You have then put part of the code inside an

```
if rising_edge(clock) then
```

which limits activity to just the rising edge, which is good.  The rest of your code is unfortunately outside of that `if` clause, and so is described as operating on every edge of the clock, either rising or falling.  In simulation this will be fine, but the synthesiser cannot find any flipflops which can do that, hence the error.

Other things to note - you need to reset or initialise your counter somehow.  Either with a reset signal, so that any time the reset signal is high, the counter is set back to all zeros.  Or using an initialisation statement.

You can get away without them for pure synthesis, as the sythesiser will (in the absence of init or reset code) automatically set the counter to all zeros when the FPGA starts up.  It's poor-form though as:

- it won't work in simulation and simulation is vital.  You may not have realised this yet, but you will eventually!
- if you port the code to another architecture which cannot magically initialise things, you wil get random 1s and 0s in the counter at startup.  This may or may not matter, but it's best to avoid having to decide.

Comment: "The rest of your code is unfortunately outside of that if clause, and so is described as operating on every edge of the clock, either rising or falling." But how? I'm using only rising edges. How did i go outside of that if clause?

Comment: You're better with a single `if rising_edge(clk) then` and put everything else inside.  Otherwise the synthesiser might not recognise it (as it uses "template matching" to find appropriate structures in the code)

Answer (score -2):

Besides the bad synchronous description there is also bad coding style :)

First off all you should not use variables in a process if you want to describe a counter. So use a signal declared in the architecture region.

2.
Decide what signal type you want to use for counters: unsigned or integer. I would advice unsigned.

3.
Signal A is not in the sensitivity list. But adding A to the sensitivity list of your process is no solution, because having two different clocks (clock and A) in one process is (a) not supported by every synthesis tool and (b) bad coding style => so use a second process for the second counter which is using a second clock.

4.
You are using A in a 'if rising_edge(...) then' statement. Synthesis tools would infer a (new) clock signal for the signal given in brackets. So your description would lead to an asynchronous description which is also bad style. A good style would be to derive a clock enable signal from fcounter(x) which enables a second counter (counter_A). counter_A is also clocked with your main clock 'clock'

5.
fcounter has no init value despite it's a register.

6.
Why has fcounter 25 bits? you are using only 7 bits.
Besides that, using bit 6 in fcounter(6) will result in a by 128 (2^7) divided clock.
Using fcounter(0) represents a toggle flip flop, which outputs f/2. fcounter(1) -> f74 and so on...

So, how should it look like?

```
architecture [...]
  [...]
  signal fcounter : unsigned(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal counter_a : unsigned(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  process(clock)
  bein
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      -- I'm using one more bits for the counter overflow, which resets the fcounter
      if (fcounter(6) = '1') then
        fcounter <= (others => '0');
      else
        fcounter <= fcounter + 1;
      end if;

      -- enable counter_A every 64 cycles
      if (fcounter(6) = '1') then
        counter_A <= counter_A + 1;
        [...]
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end;
```

But in the end there is another question: What should this module do? Do you want to create a new /64 clock or do you want to create some kind of a reset? There are other ways to generate these kinds of signals.

### Reply to Mehmet's comment:

Normally a pulse train is generated by a shift register of n bits, which is reseted to all ones and the input is assigned with '0'. For short pulse trains it's a good solution, but in your case a counter is more resource efficient :)

Example for short pulse (constant) trains

```
input <= '0';
--input <= any_signal;

process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    if (reset = '1') then
      pulse_train <= (others => '1');
    else
      pulse_train <= pulse_train(pulse_train'high - 1 downto 0) & input;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

output <= pulse_train(pulse_train'high);
```

Ok, in the case of supplying an external low frequency IC with a derived clock, it's ok to use a counter. If the counter can't supply the recommended frequency and duty cycle, you can use a counter to produce f_out*2 and feed this signal through a toggle flip flop. The T-FF restores the duty cycle to 50/50 and divides the clock by two to f_out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interested answer. It's gonna be useful for me. I wanna make a pulse train which consists 40 consecutive 1s to hard reset an IC. Also, i wanna be able to adjust it's frequency because of the IC's frequency boundaries. Thanks for replies.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no reason at all to avoid variables!

Comment: @MartinThompson Because there is a way in describing things in VHDL doesn't mean that you should use it! Especially for VHDL beginners variables are no good choise.

Comment: @Paebbels avoiding well-supported language features which enable cleaner code and higher abstraction without *very* good reason is essentially [cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), beginner or not!